# Android Yandex mapkit route

Tags: android, mapkit, yandex

I work on project with yandexmapkit-android. Library link is https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-android

Documentation is very weak and github page is not fresh. Last update is 3 years ago.

I wanna draw route between two point but i can't find any function or method for this or example

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

```
// add points
List<RequestPoint> requestPoints = new ArrayList<>();  
DrivingOptions drivingOptions = new DrivingOptions();   
DrivingRouter drivingRouter = MapKitFactory.getInstance().createDrivingRouter();
            DrivingSession drivingSession = drivingRouter.requestRoutes(
                requestPoints, drivingOptions, new DrivingSession.DrivingRouteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDrivingRoutes(List<DrivingRoute> routes) {
                        if (routes != null
                            && !routes.isEmpty()) {
                            DrivingRoute route = routes.get(0);

                        BoundingBox box = BoundingBoxHelper.getBounds(route.getGeometry());
                        CameraPosition boundingBoxPosition = yandexMap.getMap()
                            .cameraPosition(box);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrivingRoutesError(Error error) {
                    //showErrorMessage                    }
            });
```

You can easily use this method and set camera position

Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, there are two ways to do it.
The first is calling Yandex Navigator as external application: https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-android/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81.%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8

The second is using Yandex JS API with WebView: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/route-docpage/

Answer (score 0):

[see yandex mapkit demo](https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/yandex/mapkitdemo/MasstransitRoutingActivity.java)

```
 mtRouter = MapKitFactory.getInstance().createMasstransitRouter();
    mtRouter.requestRoutes(ROUTE_START_LOCATION, ROUTE_END_LOCATION,
            new MasstransitOptions(new ArrayList<String>(), new ArrayList<String>(),
                    // Specify departure time or arrival time here
                    new TimeOptions()),
            this);
```